# Does askubuntu give points by visiting the day of your birthday?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering since today is my birthday if askubuntu or the stackexchange network had some kind of additional points for visiting on the day of your birthday. It happens once a year and maybe a "birthday badge" is not a bad idea.

**Birthday Badge** - Happy birthday from "Stack Exchange Site you are visiting"

Comment: You get a badge for being active in the community each year. It's not for your actual birthday, but it does represent you "Askubuntu birthday".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, there is no such badge.

See also:

- [Display a "Happy Birthday" message when a user logs in on their birthday [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47718/display-a-happy-birthday-message-when-a-user-logs-in-on-their-birthday)
- [Please award reputation equal to a user's age on their birthday as a gift](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/please-award-reputation-equal-to-a-users-age-on-their-birthday-as-a-gift)